# i want different navbar on my admin routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.js"
import Footer from "./components/Footer.js"
import './index.css'
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage/HomePage.js";

import {
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";




import ProductPage from "./pages/ProductPage.js";
import  CreateProduct  from './pages/admin/CreateProduct'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
      
      
      <Navbar/>
     
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage/>} />
        <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductPage />}/>
        
      </Routes>
     
      <Footer/>

      
    <Routes>
       <Route exact path="sarangAdmin/create-product" element={<CreateProduct/>} />
    </Routes>

      
      </>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you can see in the route of sarangAdmin i dont want the default navbar and fotter appear i want to create a new one for the admin the problem is then when i going on this route i am seeing navbar nad footer but not my create componenet what i want is that i should not see the navbar and footer component and see my create-product componenet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better that you change **Footer & Navbar** component

> at first add location to app params `app({ location })`
> then

```js
{location.pathname!=='sarangAdmin/create-product'?<Footer/>}
```

> I hope this code will help you

```js
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.js"
import Footer from "./components/Footer.js"
import './index.css'
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage/HomePage.js";
import {Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";

import ProductPage from "./pages/ProductPage.js";
import  CreateProduct  from './pages/admin/CreateProduct'

const App = ({location}) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {location.pathname!=='sarangAdmin/create-product'?<Navbar/>:null}
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage/>} />
        <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductPage />}/>
        <Route exact path="sarangAdmin/create-product" element={<CreateProduct/>} />
      </Routes>
      {location.pathname!=='sarangAdmin/create-product'?<Footer/>:null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What you want to say lese eloborate

Comment: put `{location.pathname!=='sarangAdmin/create-product'?<Footer/>}` code instead of `</Footer>`

Comment: I am not a advance developeer still not understanding sir

Comment: please use the code instead your code